# Recurrence relation and integral mistake

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

We know $$I_n=\int _0^1\:\frac{x^n}{x^2+1}dx\:,\:n\ge 0$$

and have show that: $$\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(1-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}+...+\left(-1\right)^{n-1}\cdot \frac{1}{2n-1}\right)=I_0$$

$$I\:calculate\ I_0=\frac{\pi }{4}$$ and I find the following recurrence relation: $$I_{2n}=\frac{1}{2n-1}-I_{2n-2},\:n\ge 2$$ How can I prove that limit is $\frac{\pi}{4}$ ?

Comment: Just compute $I_0$.

Comment: I calculate that, is pi/4

Comment: Normally, it's a basic integral: $\displaystyle \int\dfrac{\mathrm d\mkern 1.5mu x}{1+x^2}=\arctan x$.

Comment: This is an awful title that does not at all give meaning to the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have:
$$ I_{n+2}+I_n = \int_{0}^{1} x^n\,dx = \frac{1}{n+1} $$
as well as:
$$ I_n = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^n}{1+x^2}\,dx \leq \int_{0}^{1}x^n\,dx = \frac{1}{n}$$
hence:
$$ I_0 = (I_0+I_2)-(I_2+I_4)+(I_4+I_6)-\ldots+(-1)^m\left(I_{2m}+I_{2m+2}\right)-(-1)^m I_{2m+2} $$
leads to:
$$ I_0 = \sum_{k=0}^{m}\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}-(-1)^m I_{2m+2}=\sum_{k=0}^{m}\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}+O\left(\frac{1}{m}\right). $$
However,
$$ I_0 = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{x^2+1}=\left.\arctan x\right|_{0}^{1} = \arctan 1 = \frac{\pi}{4}$$
proving:
$$ \sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}=\frac{\pi}{4}.$$

Comment: Thank you man! My teacher don't explain me about that and I don't know how to continue... so if I know a recurrence relation can I prove every term from that limit

Answer (score 1):

It is trivial to show that

$$\begin{align}
I_0 &= \frac{\pi}{4}\\
I_1 &= \frac12 \log(2)
\end{align}$$

Now observe that for $n\ge2$, 
$$\begin{align}
I_n =& \int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{1+x^2} dx\\
&=\int_0^1 x^{n-2}\frac{x^2}{1+x^2} dx\\
&=\int_0^1 x^{n-2}\left(1-\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right) dx\\
&= \frac{1}{n-1} -I_{n-2}
\end{align}$$

Given the seed values for even and odd $n$ along with the recursive relationship, one can easily proceed to examine convergence of subsequences of $I_n$.

---

Since we have $I_n+I_{n-2}=\frac{1}{n-1}$ we have for the even terms, $I_{2n}+I_{2n-2}=\frac{1}{2n-1}$.  Now, we can form the sums

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^{n+1} \frac{1}{2n-1}&=\sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^{n+1}\left(I_{2n}+I_{2n-2}\right) \\
&=I_0+(-1)^{N+1}I_{2N}
\end{align}$$

where the equality result was obtained by observing the telescoping nature of the sum.  But it is easy to see that the term $I_{2N} \to 0$ as $N \to \infty$.  And so the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} \frac{1}{2n-1}=I_0=\pi /4$ as was to be shown.

---

We can also derive the result of the alternating harmonic series.  Here, we again use $I_n+I_{n-2}=\frac{1}{n-1}$, which for odd terms, $I_{2n+1}+I_{2n-1}=\frac{1}{2n}$.  Now, we can form the sums

$$\begin{align}
\frac12 \sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^{n+1} \frac{1}{n}&=\sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^{n+1}\left(I_{2n+1}+I_{2n-1}\right) \\
&=I_1+(-1)^{N+1}I_{2N+1}
\end{align}$$

where the equality result was obtained by observing the telescoping nature of the sum.  But it is easy to see that the term $I_{2N+1} \to 0$ as $N \to \infty$.  And so the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{n} =2I_1=\log(2)$, which recovers the well-known result.

Comment: My pleasure!  I don't understand why there were down votes here.  I neutralized one of them.